# iOSのUITableViewCellの再利用がうまくいかない(swift)

Tags: swift

Xcode7 beta5のSwiftを用いてTwitterクライアントを作成しています。
タイムラインの表示のためにUITableViewCellを用いていますがうまくいきません。
以下がコードです。

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        print("nil")
    }
    タイムラインの表示処理
    return cell!
}
```

状態としてはdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifierの部分でブレークポイントを挟むとこの行で停止するのでこの部分までは到達しているようです。またUITableViewCellはStoryBoardで配置しておりidentifierも"Cell"にしております。
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifierの次の行にブレークポイントをはさんでも次の行に
到達せず、またdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifierのところでstep inをしてもそのまま
何もおこらずにブレークポイントから抜け出します。
まだiOSアプリの開発を勉強中なので単純なミスがあるかもしれませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

以下、回答に値する内容ではないかもしれません。あらかじめお断りしておきます。というのは、

> タイムラインの表示のためにUITableViewCellを用いていますがうまくいきません。

どういう現象が起きているために、「うなくい」かないと判断なさっているのか、不明だからです。

ご提示のコードは、このように書きかえたほうがいいと思います。

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    // タイムラインの表示処理
    return cell
}
```

[UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:)

これによると、`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)`の返り値は、

> Return Value
>   A UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. This method always returns a valid cell.

Optional型ではないので、`nil`になりません。そして、型が`AnyObject`になっていますが、じっさいは`UITableViewCell`であることが確実なので、いちいち返り値が`nil`であるとか、`UITableViewCell`でないとかの可能性を考慮する必要がありません。

以上の修正を施したのち、どのような意図しない現象が起きるのか、説明いただけるとさいわいです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいたところを変更しましたが、うまくいきません。うまくいかないというのは起動した直後(おそらくこの関数に入る前)では、ツイートを投稿するボタンを押したり、何も表示されていないUITableViewを動かしたりすることができるのですが、このdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifierが実行されると全くアプリの操作ができなくなってしまいます。
しかし、かといってコンソールにエラーが出力されていたりXcodeを見るかぎりどこかで停止しているわけでもなさそうなので、一体何が起きているのかわからず困っています。意図している動作としてはdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier実行後に取得したセル上のtextViewなどに自身のタイムラインを表示する処理に移行するはずですが、dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier以降の行にブレークポイントをはさんでも到達しておりません。